# flash to ios signing certificate password

Tags: ios, flash, command-prompt

I am trying to make an flash project for i-pad.  I am going through it step by step and each step has worked except for when i made the p12 certificate it never asked for me to put in a password.

Now when I am trying to compile I left the password blank and it says error the password may be wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your .p12 certificate from the keychain and add it again, but this time, fill in the password

Comment: Or use keychain application on your mac.

Comment: what do you mean use console what is console?

Comment: I mean command promp. The tool that you used for importing the .p12 key in the first place

Comment: when i create the p12 file it doesnt ask for a password, any idea why?

Comment: What IDE are you using for compiling your project? Did you follow the steps described on developer.apple.com for creating signing certificate?

Comment: I am very new to this I do not know what an IDE even is.  The problem I think is that I am making a flash project from PC and want to run it on an apple i-pad I am following the steps laid out in this tutorial  

http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2011/11/30/flash-to-ios-a-step-by-step-tutorial-part-2/